# bloomberg API: field not permitted to datafeed users

Tags: c++, bloomberg

I use the bloomberg API(c++) to do a project.
I have already been able to send a request with an identity.
For example, I send a request like this:

```
    Request request = session.createRequest("ReferenceDataRequest");
    request.append("securities", "IBM US Equity");
    request.append("fields", "PX_LAST");
    session.sendRequest(request, identity, CorrelationId(20));
```

After sending this request, I get a response.
But when I release the response, I always get an exception: "NO_AUTH, field not permitted to datafeed users".
the function to deal with the response:

```
void handleResponseEvent(Event e, Identity identity)
{
    MessageIterator msgIter(e);
    while (msgIter.next())
    {
        Message message = msgIter.message();
        message.print(cout);
    }
}
```

I know that this is not correct because i didn't use the "identity". I think that's why I got an exception "NO_AUTH".
Could you please tell me how to release the response with the identity?

To clarify - I am using B-PIPE, rather than the D-API, to connect to Bloomberg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using B-PIPE, have you verified that your `OS_LOGON` or `APPLICATION` are authorised for the data that you are requesting?

If you download the B-PIPE package from WAPI, there is a (Windows) demo application that can be used to check your logon credentials independently of any code that you may be using...

> /path/to/BPipe/APIv3/bin/BLPAPIDemo.exe

Set your authentication type, host and port:

[image]

Then test your data request, by setting your tickers/fields/dates and clicking run:

[image]

If you get an error - e.g. EID permissioning issues - you know that you don't have the authentication for that data. If that's the case, you need to get in touch with the B-PIPE manager at your firm / Bloomberg rep.

If you don't get an error / do get the data, then the issue is in your code somewhere...

Answer (score 1):

How do you initialize 'identity' parameter that is passed to sendRequest()? If you use Desktop Api (DAPI) then identity parameter is not required, and request can be sent as follow:

```
session.sendRequest(request, CorrelationId(20));
```

Comment: I use the BPIPE to do this. So the authorization is necessary. I send the request like this: Request request =service.createRequest("ReferenceDataRequest");
  request.append("securities", "IBM US Equity");
  request.append("fields", "PX_LAST");
  request.set("returnEids", true);
  request.sendRequest(request, identity, CorrelationId(20));

Comment: Then, when I receive the response, I do like this:

Comment: double px_last = message.asElement().getElement("securityData").getElement("fieldData").getElementAsFloat64("PX_LAST");  normally i could get the PX_LAST because i have sent it as a request. But i get an exception. I dont know why. Maybe i misunderstood something about bloomberg api BPIPE.

Comment: My question was: how do you initialize 'identity' object?
Identity object is initialized by first passing it to SendAuthorizationRequest() as an out parameter.

Comment: I create an identity like this: Identity identity = session.createIdentity();  then, i send it as a parametre with this: session.sendAuthorizationRequest()

Comment: session.createIdentity() simply instantiate a new identity object that must first be authorized before requesting data. Here is a C++ example:
session.sendAuthorizationRequest(authorizationRequest,
&identity,
authorizationRequestId,
&authorizationEventQueue);

More information about B-Pipe authorization can be found in http://www.openbloomberg.com/content/uploads/sites/2/2012/03/blpapi-developers-guide.pdf  (section 7.4 Managed B-PIPE Authorization)